# Python mitmproxy with https

Tags: python, python-3.x, mitmproxy

i am trying to create a mitmproxy script with python to redirect a request from one host to another. I've had some success with http, but cant do it with https.
I cant find on docs or anywhere. I mean, i would accept using other options or libraries to do that, but i dont want to use a full aplication, like downloading xampp or other apache server.

```
from mitmproxy.options import Options
from mitmproxy.proxy.config import ProxyConfig
from mitmproxy.proxy.server import ProxyServer
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster
import os, sys, re, datetime, json

class Addon(object):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def request(self, flow):
    # examine request here
    if flow.request.host == 'testserver.net':
        flow.request.host = 'mynewserver.com'
        print('New try ---> Bypassing.')

def response(self, flow):
    # examine response here
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

options = Options(listen_host='0.0.0.0', listen_port=8080, certs=['*=mitmproxy.pem'])
m = DumpMaster(options, with_termlog=False, with_dumper=False)
config = ProxyConfig(options)

m.server = ProxyServer(config)
m.addons.add(Addon())

try:
    print('Redirection active.')
    m.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    m.shutdown()
```

Comment: Did you get any help by just goggling for the title of your question - there seem to be plenty of examples

Comment: There’s one result “MITM can be pretty easy with Mitmproxy and Python” which sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: @barny no, i didnt.
Didnt find any result with https and certificates.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-overview/ for an introduction to addons, and at https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/addons/http-redirect-requests.py for a concrete example.